# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 - Issue posting MultiSelectList values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and new to programming (in a general sense) as well.

I'm struggling with the concept of how to post multiple database entries into my database (via my controller) based on values I'm pulling from a MultiSelectList that I've populated.

Basically, I'm trying to create a simple model that contains a State and a City, and lets the user select and save multiple City values to their account based on State/City values pulled from a separate, static database.

Here's my Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BidFetcher.Models
{
public class SPServiceLocation
{
    public int SPServiceLocationID { get; set; }
    public int SPCompanyAccountID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cities (select all that apply)")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    public virtual SPCompanyAccount SPCompanyAccount { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is a snippet of my View data (including the multi-select list for city that I have no trouble populating):

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("state", ViewBag.state as SelectList, "Select a state...",    new { @class = "chzn-select", onchange = "CityChange()" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field" id="SP_SelectCity">
        @Html.ListBox("city", ViewBag.city as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Select cities..." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
```

And here are my Create/Post Controllers:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.sessionName = HttpContext.Session["SPCompanyName"].ToString();

        var compID = HttpContext.Session["SPCompanyAccountID"].ToString();

        ViewBag.companyID = compID;

        ViewBag.state = new SelectList(simpleDB.simpleState, "simpleStateID", "simpleStateID");

        ViewBag.city = new MultiSelectList(simpleDB.simpleCity, "cityFull", "cityFull");

        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SPServiceLocation spservicelocation, FormCollection formValues)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.SPServiceLocation.Add(spservicelocation);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "SPServiceLocation");
        }

        return View(spservicelocation);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm missing something in my [HttpPost] that'll allow me to save multiple values to the **db** database, but I'm not sure what exactly it is that's missing. I've seen some posts that explain this in terms of creating an IEnumerable list, but I guess I'm just not sure I need to do that since I'm already successfully populating my MultiSelectList via a database call.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Based on the answers below, if I want to create multiple new database rows based on the results I collect from a MultiSelectList, I need to use Form collection to grab those results and parse them within my HttpPost:

And... I do not know how to do that. I assume something along these lines:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SPServiceLocation spservicelocation, FormCollection formValues)
{

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in x)
            {
            db.SPServiceLocation.Add(spservicelocation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "SPServiceLocation");
    }

    return View(spservicelocation);
}
```

Something along the lines of the above, where I create a collection based on my multiselectlist, break it into multiple variables, and step through my database.SaveChanges multiple times before I redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you imagine storing multiple cities in single string City variable?

Answer (score 0):

The trick has nothing to do with your MVC code. You have to change either your Business Layer or Data Access Layer (DAL) code to read/write to 2 different databases.

I did the same project to answer one question sometime ago. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667172/538387

I checked the code, It's still working, you can download it and check it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Tohid, but I should clarify, I'm able to successfully read from the static database and write/save to my app's database, I'm just not able to do so for multiple values at once. In this case, the code above is creating a new record in my database, but only that one record for the first city I select (and ignoring selections two through three, four, five). What I want to be able to do is create a single record for each selected city that sits in the MultiSelectList.

Comment: Ok. Got it, I'll answer you in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

When user submits the Create forms and application flows to `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create` action, all of the form data live in `formValues` parameter.

You have to read those data from `formValues` (like: `formValues["companyID"]`, build appropriate model object from them, and then update the db.

Comment: Thanks Tohid! This is exactly the path I'm attempting to take, any thoughts on how I would structure this for a MultiSelectList?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList()`, `@Html.ListBox()` and any Html Helper that builds form <input > element, has a given "name". So inside `[HttpPost]` method you can retrieve data by using their names; In your case: `formValues["state"]` and `formValues["city"]`.