# MVC3 - Razor, Ajax.BeginForm - client side - OnBegin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ajax.beginform

When i click the submit button, i directly go to my action. Following 2 are not happening:

1. My client side beginForm method is not invoked at this time. Which i want.
2. Request.IsAjaxRequest is false even though my model has the form input

Trying to find an answer for this problem. The same code works in MVC2, so i must be missing some thing here.

Following 2 MS js files are referenced:

```
<!-- MS AJAX -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
```

Form Code:

```
@{
        using (Ajax.BeginForm(ActionNames.Index, ControllerNames.CustomerSearch, new {Area = ""}, new AjaxOptions
                                                                                                      {
                                                                                                          HttpMethod = "Post",
                                                                                                          OnBegin = "CustomerSearch.beginForm",
                                                                                                          OnSuccess = "CustomerSearch.successForm"
                                                                                                      }, new {id = "CustomerSearchForm"}))
        {

... form items ...
}
}
```

Form as it displays on the page:

```
<form action="/CustomerSearch" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="CustomerSearch.beginForm" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-success="CustomerSearch.successForm" id="CustomerSearchForm" method="post">

... Other Form Items ...
<input type="image" src="/App_Themes/Main/Images/ResponseAction/Buttons/btn_submit.gif" alt="Submit" id="SubmitButton" />
</form>
```

And here is my CustomerSearch.js, on page load alert(2) shows just fine:

```
var CustomerSearch = {
    enums: {
        buttonId: "SubmitButton",
        searchResultsContainerId: "CustomerSearchResults"
    },
    beginForm: function () {
        alert(1);
        var $button = $("#" + CustomerSearch.enums.buttonId);
        jMessage("Processing request...", $button, true, false);
        return true;
    },
    successForm: function (context) {
        var $button = $("#" + CustomerSearch.enums.buttonId);
        var $searchResults = $("#" + CustomerSearch.enums.searchResultsContainerId);
        var data = context.get_data();

        jMessageHide();
        $searchResults.html(data).fadeIn(500);
    }
};

alert(2);
```

My unobtrusive javascript enabled is set to true in web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[With MVC3](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034221) the unobtrusive Ajax helpers:

- Ajax.ActionLink
- Ajax.RouteLink
- Ajax.BeginForm
- Ajax.BeginRouteForm

are using the `jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js` file.

So you need to include that js file instead of the MicrosoftAjax ones
(MicrosoftAjax files are deprecated in MVC3 and not shipped with MVC4 beta):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Getting late for the class, will check this out as soon as i am back.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am now using jquery $.ajax. Following also helped:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor