# how to call a method in controller asynchronously in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have to call the method in the controller from view, but not using any click, so I am thinking to do it using the following line of code:

```
@Html.RenderAction("Replies", new { id= item.ID})
```

and my method in the controller is like this:

```
public post Replies(int Id)  
    {  
        post posts = new post();  
        posts = new Data_Access().Get_Replies(Id);   
        return posts;  
    }
```

but this is showing error saying that "can not implicitly convert type void to object"
can any one please help me..
thanks

Comment: You should use ajax. Visit this site. it will help you.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor

Answer (score 1):

`RenderAction` writes the result directly to the page and returns `void`.
`@whatever` writes the result of `whatever` to the page.

Since `RenderAction` doesn't return anything, it cannot be used in an `@` block.

Instead, you should write `@Html.Action(...)`.
`Html.Action` returns the result as an `HelperResult` object.