# MVC4: ModelState.IsValid always returns true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model-validation

I have a PartialView that contains a form that asynchronously posts data to my controller. The controller will add the user if the `ModelState` is valid, if not, it will return the PartialView with the invalid model. The problem I'm running into is that the `ModelState` is always valid no matter what. I can see that the form is being serialized properly and all the properties for `DynamicActionUserModel.RegisterModel` are being populated.

I don't understand why this would be the case but is it possible the Model Binding isn't working because I have a model within a model?

Here's my code...

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<RobotDog.Models.UserModel>
<!-- other stuff -->
<div class="createUser">
    @Html.Partial("_UserPartial", new DynamicActionUserModel { Action = "CreateUser", RegisterModel = new RegisterModel() })    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('form.ajax').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        location.reload(true);
                    } else {
                        $('.createUser').html(result);                          
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**_UserPartial View**

```
@model RobotDog.Models.DynamicActionUserModel

@using(Html.BeginForm(Model.Action,"Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajax" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration unsuccessful. Please correct errors and try again.")

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegisterModel.Email, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "Email"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegisterModel.UserName, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "User Name"})
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.RegisterModel.Password, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "Password"})
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.RegisterModel.SelectedRoles, Model.RegisterModel.Roles)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**DynamicActionUserModel**

```
public class DynamicActionUserModel {
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel {
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string[] SelectedRoles { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Roles { 
        get { return new MultiSelectList(System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()); }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(DynamicActionUserModel model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        foreach(var value in ModelState.Values) {
            foreach (var error in value.Errors) {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return PartialView("_UserPartial", model);
    }

    try { 
        ...
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ... }

    return PartialView("_UserPartial", model);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you take the AllowEmptyStrings=false out?  FYI, this is the default anyways, and MVC ignores this property (it's purpose is for DynamicData).  I've seen it cause weird validation problems though.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use @placeholder, the @ is used on class because class is a reserved word in c#, it's not used on non-reserved attribute names.

Comment: Are you not including jquery.validation in your layout?  I'm not sure if including it as you are might be causing problems, since it may be getting included twice

Comment: It's also bad practice to do data access in your view model.  I assume the Roles property loads something from the database?  Shouldn't be causing this problem though.  The reason it's bad practice is that it effectively makes the view database aware.

Comment: @MystereMan thanks, there is a lot of good info here. I'm learning the mvc framework and this much appreciated advice.

Comment: Did you solve your question? I am having the exact same problem, and I have a similar scenario where I want it to be validating a Model-inside-a-Model, so perhaps that is a key part of problem...

Comment: And am also using ajax... maybe that is it?

Comment: So it turns out the answer for me is: it was neither! I did a rebase which removed my [Required] attributes and I didn't even realize it.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith I think the solution would be to pass the specific model you want to be validated to the action instead of the view model. And instead of using `Html.BeginForm` with jQuery I would use `Ajax.BeginForm`. The `Ajax` helper will handle all the client side async requests as well as validation. Here's a good example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor