# How to update the view when clic in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my razor view, my model has one property composed only by a `get`.

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.QuizCompletedViewModel

<p>@Model.Property1</p>
```

By default, this property starts with the value: 10. And all the time has that value in view. I would like when I press clic on a `img` tag, this property can be updated (because all the time the value persisted), how can I update the property without refresh the page?

Comment: need to use ajax for that

Comment: I see, so how can I invoke to update the label since jquery using ajax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor here is a good explanation

Comment: Excuse but I haven't understand how can indicate that I'm just interested in that property to ajax method? In the last example, uses the `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Modify the view to make the counter addressable by jquery:

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.QuizCompletedViewModel

<p id="my-counter">@Model.Property1</p>
```

Now, do you need this incremented value on the server?

IF YOU DO NOT need this incremented value sent to the server:

Step 2) Increment the value on the client using javascript/jquery:

```
$("#my-image").click(function () { 
    var theValue = parseInt($("#my-counter").html());
    theValue = theValue + 10;
    $("#my-counter").html(theValue);
});
```

IF YOU DO NEED TO INCREMENT ON THE SERVER:

Step 2) Create a controller action to handle the increment

```
public ActionResult Increment(int currentValue)
{
    // save to the database, or do whatever
    int newValue = currentValue + 10;
    DatabaseAccessLayer.Save(newValue);

    Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.QuizCompletedViewModel model = new Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.QuizCompletedViewModel();

    model.Property1 = newValue;

    // If no exception, return the new value
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Step 3) Create a partial view which will return ONLY the new value

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.QuizCompletedViewModel

@Model.Property1
```

Step 4) Modify the jquery to post to this new action, which returns the new count, and displays it

```
$("#my-image").click(function () { 
    $.get('/MyController/Increment/' + $("#my-counter").html(), function(data) {
        $("#my-counter").html(data);
    });
});
```

Code is untested, but I think pretty close, and hopefully this gives the right idea.