# MVC4 Pass model via Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have tried to follow some [good posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor) here to get this to work but every time i click the ajax postback the break point in my controller shows a model with null values.  This page displays model values for viewing only, but I have tried putting them in their own form and also wrapping them in the ajax form and nothing seems to work.

```
@model VendorProfileIntranet.Models.VendorProfile

$(function () {
$("form").submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#message").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectVendor", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="post", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId="message" }))
{
    <div style="float:right; width:500px">
        <div id="message"></div>
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Select Vendor" />
    </div>
```

The view is really long (just displays model values for viewing) abbreviated here.

```
<div id="viewform">
    <div id="viewform-contact" style="float:left;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProfileID)
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Website)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Website)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address1)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2)&nbsp;
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address2)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.State)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zip)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Zip)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-fieldwide">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorNotes)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="view-fieldwide">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VendorNotes)
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Controller. I have tried the above in one or two forms. With the above code the model contains all empty values except the ProfileID which is stuffed in a hidden input field.  I think passing the model should work without having to create a hidden field for every model value?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SelectVendor(VendorProfile pageModel)
    {
        // handle selected vendor
            _DAL.SelectVendor(pageModel.ProfileID);
            return Content("This Vendor has been selected", "text/html");
    }
```

**ANSWER**

The model values are not binded due to the use of DisplayFor

Comment: You seem to be lacking input elements in your form'

Comment: @Forty-Two There is a button that when clicked should pass back the model that is the other form (not shown) and insert a record in db and update message in div tag that it was successful.  I tried putting all the form elements in the ajax form and that didn't work either, so one form or two forms didn't work. I know I am missing something.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your view?

Comment: @mattytommo  See above.  I suspect something wrong with the way I have the one or two forms setup.  Like I said I have tried this a couple ways already. THx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you're actually expecting to see items in your Model that you have put in your form using `DisplayFor`. `DisplayFor` fields **will not post**, they are simply for display. In order to post those values back, you'd need a `HiddenFor` for each of the field that you want to post, in order for model binding to work it's magic.

Comment: I have tried one form and two forms.  I actually tried exactly what you suggested above (and tried it again) and my model is still null when the the controller breakpoint is hit. :(

Comment: @Vic What is in Request.Form when you debug?

Comment: Interesting...  It only contains 7 keys, it has the ProfileID (from hidden input) and of the remaining 2 dozen items on the page from the model it only contains 6 checkbox values that are all false (even though one on the page shows true.  This is going with everything stuffed into one form and not modifying the jquery code.

Comment: @Vic Request.Form won't contain the other values that you have `DisplayFor` for, you'll have to have `HiddenFor`s for each of those in order to model bind. What happens if you submit the form without jquery?

Comment: Ah, light bulb moment. Thx. It works the same even without the jquery. I am looking into a variation of using TextBoxFor with readonly that would display all the fields and allow model binding (instead of using both DisplayFor and HiddenFor)

Comment: @Vic No problems, glad I could help! You could create your own overload of the `DisplayFor` method that actually rendered the hidden field too.