# How to use Simple Ajax Beginform in Asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, form-helpers, ajax.beginform

I am new in Asp.net MVC and i researched about `Ajax.BeginForm` but when i apply codes it did not work. Can you share very simple example with `Ajax.Beginform` with View, Controller, Model?
Thanks.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Simple example: Form with textbox and Search button.

If you write "name" into the `textbox` and submit form, it will brings you patients with "name" in table.

**View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetPatients", "Patient", new AjaxOptions {//GetPatients is name of method in PatientController
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, //target element(#patientList) will be replaced
    UpdateTargetId = "patientList",
    LoadingElementId = "loader" // div with .gif loader - that is shown when data are loading   
}))
{
    string patient_Name = "";
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>patient_Name) //text box with name and id, that it will pass to controller
    <input  type="submit" value="Search" />
}

@* ... *@
<div id="loader" class=" aletr" style="display:none">
    Loading...<img src="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
@Html.Partial("_patientList") @* this is view with patient table. Same view you will return from controller *@
```

**_patientList.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<YourApp.Models.Patient>

<table id="patientList" >
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
    </th>       
</tr>
@foreach (var patient in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patient.Number)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

**Patient.cs**

```
public class Patient
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Number{ get; set; }
}
```

**PatientController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult GetPatients(string patient_Name="")
{
   var patients = yourDBcontext.Patients.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(patient_Name))
   return PartialView("_patientList", patients);
}
```

And also as TSmith said in comments, don´t forget to install *jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax* library through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax).

Comment: For others, don't forget the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax lib needed for this.

Comment: I have created a project in VS 2013, MVC5, I have Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax, through NuGet, but it doesn't work, it opens in a new window :( This used to work in MVC4. Thoughts?

Comment: if you add @Html.Partial("_patientList") you get an error that this view must have IEnumerable<Patient>

Comment: Best tutorial on using `Ajax.BeginForm`! My only problem was misspelling the unobtrusive lib in BundlesConfig.cs :) Thanks, @Alamakanambra!

Answer (score 34):

All This Work :)

**Model**

```
  public partial class ClientMessage
    {
        public int IdCon { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }  
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   public class TestAjaxBeginFormController : Controller{  

 projectNameEntities db = new projectNameEntities();

        public ActionResult Index(){  
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult GetClientMessages(ClientMessage Vm) {
            var model = db.ClientMessages.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(Vm.Name));
            return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
        } 
}
```

**View index.cshtml**

```
@model  projectName.Models.ClientMessage 
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script>
    //\\\\\\\ JS  retrun message SucccessPost or FailPost
    function SuccessMessage() {
        alert("Succcess Post");
    }
    function FailMessage() {
        alert("Fail Post");
    } 
</script>

<h1>Page Index</h1> 

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetClientMessages", "TestAjaxBeginForm", null , new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "SuccessMessage",
    OnFailure = "FailMessage" ,
    UpdateTargetId = "resultTarget"  
}, new { id = "MyNewNameId" })) // set new Id name for  Form
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name) 
     <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 

}


<div id="resultTarget">  </div>
```

**View _PartialView.cshtml**

```
@model  IEnumerable<projectName.Models.ClientMessage >
<table> 

@foreach (var item in Model) { 

    <tr> 
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdCon)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
    </tr>

}

</table>
```

Answer (score 28):

Besides the previous post instructions, I had to install the package [Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/2.0.30506) and add to the view the following line

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```