# How to use Partial view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I do have a textbox and a submit button. All I have to do is to get the records based on the date provided and when a get request is made I just want to display a textbox and button. For Post request I want to check the date matches with the record and want to display the data within same view. How is that possible. I am having the view as

```
@model IEnumerable<ShopOnline.Models.Order>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Date").datepicker({dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"});
});
</script>
@using(Html.BeginForm())   
{
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Enter Date</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Date")</td>       
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
}
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Order</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
    <td>Select Date</td>
    <td>@item.Order_Id</td>
    <td>@item.Product_Name</td>
    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
    <td>@item.Amount</td>
    <td>@item.Order_Date</td>
</tr>
    }
    </tbody>
```

Here is the controller Action Method

```
 public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        return View(db.Orders.ToList());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Admin(DateTime Date)
    {
        var record = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Order_Date ==Date).ToList();
        return View(record);
    }
```

Now here the problem is I will get all the records displayed if I perform GET Request and I only want to display a textbox and button on GET request and  while if I perform a POST Request I want to get list of records in the same view with a textbox and button. So can Partial View be applied here and how will that work

Comment: If partial could be utilised for this or any other options...

Comment: use ``Ajax.BeginForm()``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad so what it does

Comment: google it **asp.net mvc ajax form example**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/how-to-use-simple-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-4 and alseo see:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how to get the record based on date I got the code as per your links but how  if I use

Comment: are you able to post the date to action of controller via **Html.BeginForm()** ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am able to do that. But it is returning null

Comment: @EhsanSajjad any alternate solution

Comment: instead of ``DateTime`` use ``string`` parameter in action, when you are able to get Date then go on converting it to **Ajax.BeginForm** way

Comment: @EhsanSajjad should there be only one action method specified within the link stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/ There should be one more action method to respond get request is that

Comment: Yes get request on separate action

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the one specified by me above is that correct ? and then do it require any POST method.....plz specify

Answer (score 0):

My controller code to access partial view

```
public ActionResult ItemsPartialView()
{
    List<Item> inventoryDetails = new List<Item>();
    return PartialView("ItemsView", inventoryDetails);
}
```

**My Js**

```
 $('#ItemView').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ItemsPartialView")',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ItemView').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

**My Orginal View**

```
<h4 > MY orginal View </h4>

<div id="ItemView">
    @Html.Partial("ItemsView", new Item())
</div>
```

**Partial View :** The partial View fileName is ItemsView

```
@model WebSite.Models.Item
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ItemsView";
 }

<div>
   Hai this is my partial view
</div>
```

Comment: Let me does it worth.