# Showing and posting in separated actions in a main view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I would like to explain my scenary: I have a form that is composed by 2 other partial views.

The idea is the following

1. The main Form show details about a Budget.
2. The second show a form to send messages.
3. The third show a form to send offer bids;

I would like that, when I do a Post in the 2nd ot 3rd form, the application return the main form. but, it is returning the form that was Posted.

It would work like I was using IFRAME... in other words, when I do a Post, it reflect only in the form that was Posted.

I am doing this form with MVC in C#.

Any tip?

I tried to use **[ChildActionOnly]**, but I suppose that isn't what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly,you must use "return View("MainView");" instead "return View();"

Comment: but, how could I handle when the model isn't valid? For example, if the user miss to fill a field, then ModelState.AddModelError will be empty. How to handle that?

Comment: if you used RenderPartial() for render the 2nd , 3rd PartialView's ,modelstate is accessible .in those views.

Comment: if 2nd and 3rd form data do not exist in main model you must use the ajax request for send forms.

Comment: I'm trying to use Ajax request.. if it work properly, I give you as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

The right Answer is:

1. I created a new View;
2. I changed the strucure Html.Beginform to Ajax.BeginForm;
3. Used the jqueryunobtrusive.

You can see an example here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/how-to-use-simple-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-4)