# Asp.net mvc: how to send event back to server without page refresh

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have one question about about ASP.NET

In Razor, what is the command used to create a button to send an event back to the controller without refreshing the page when clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Simple Ajax Beginform in Asp.net MVC 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/how-to-use-simple-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: You can use Ajax.BeginForm for a submit button, or via ajax via JS.

Answer (score 0):

you should use java script ajax call to server  , there is no code behind event as there was in asp.net form . or if you want pure single page app , better use web api instead of mvc . in web api you can post json and get json as result , and then use client side framework (angular, ember ) to loop or show data on page.