# ajax html.BeginForm() post to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

As the title for my question states, i wish to post a registration form to my controller via ajax instead of a submit button within a `BeginForm`.

HTML looks like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)<br />
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)<br />
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)<br />
<p>
    <button type="submit" id="sbmt">Register</button>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</p>
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Registration(Users model)
{
//code for registration of user
}
```

i want my ajax to pass just the model to my controller. In other words, i dont want to declare multiple string arguments in my controller.

My ajax so far looks something like this:

```
$("#sbmt").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("Register", "Auth")",
            data: { WHAT SHOULD I PASS HERE? },
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status === "success") {
                $("#MailFoot").hide();
                $("#ty").text("Thank you!");
            }
            else {
                alert("Error sending email");
            }
    });
});
```

I have no idea how i should wrap my data and pass it to my controller. Any help is therefore appreciated.

Comment: Its just `data: $('form').serialize(),` (and don't use `Ajax.BeginForm()` - the `$.ajax()` methods gve you far more flexibility

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you give me an example of how that would look? would it require me to wrap it inside a form element?

Comment: Your form controls just need to be inside `<form>` tags (which they should be anyway). And you do not handle the `.click()` event - you should be handling the forms `.submit()` event

Comment: so what you say,  is that my selector should be `$('form').submit(function()` too?

Comment: Yes, and if you want client side validation, you should be testing `if($(this).valid())` and cancel the submit if its not.

Comment: Thats great! thank you :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use `AjaxExtensions.BeginForm` you can check how to use it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx). If you want an example you can view the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/how-to-use-simple-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-4).

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you :-)

Comment: your welcome, remember it was useful please mark the answer as its solve the question :)