# Ajax.BeginForm does not insert partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, partial, ajax.beginform

Running ASP.NET MVC 2015 with C#. 
Trying to add a partial view as a result of @using (Ajax.BeginForm(...)
All it does is to open a new page with my partial view in it. I found some answers in stackoverflow, but none works for me, unless I missed something.

Scenario: 
[index page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRmhf.png)
Type A, B or C and partial view is expected below the current page

[new page unexpected here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78TOZ.png)
But it does open a new page instead

**Controler**:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult TestPartial()
    {
        ChoiceViewModel vm = new ChoiceViewModel();
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectChoice(ChoiceViewModel vm)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        if (vm.MyChoice == "A")
            return PartialView("APartial");

        if (vm.MyChoice == "B")
            return PartialView("BPartial");

        if (vm.MyChoice == "C")
            return PartialView("CPartial");

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
   @Html.Partial("TestPartial")
</div>
<br/>
<div id="GoesHere">
</div>
```

**TestPartial.cshtml:**

```
@model TestPartial.ViewModels.ChoiceViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectChoice", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "GoesHere", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
   <div class="form-group">
       <p>Give your choice please: A,B or C</p>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyChoice, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Select">
   </div>
}
```

**APartial.cshtml** (as well as B and C...)

```
<p>This is A choice</p>
```

**Notes:**

- Yes, web.config has UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true and ClientValidationEnabled=true
- Yes, I installed the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax package

Can you tell me what I missed or did wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: It means you making a normal submit which happens because your scripts are not loaded correctly or are loaded in the wrong order.

Comment: do you not need to pass your model to partialView?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks for the answer, but not very clear to me. Can you tell me exactly in that dummy scenario what would need to be changed ?

Comment: @Sarhang: does not change the behaviour if I redirect the view model to the partial views.

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/how-to-use-simple-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: @Sarhang. Thanks! My missing piece was to assert the script line : <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was missing the unobtrusive-ajax inclusion line in my cshtml :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```