# How to display partial HTML after post action in the same HTML?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to display `partial html` after `POST` on my `Form`.

First, i have `Index.cshtml` file:

```
@model Models.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var taskList = ViewBag.TaskList;
}

@section styles {
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="@Href("~/Content/Index.css")" />
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <section id="sendedTaskForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("FromInput", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "col-md2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 100, @rows = 20 })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Code)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TaskId)
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TaskId, Model.Tasks)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login " onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Login", "Home") + "'");" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
}
```

After clicking `Submit` button, form is passed to my method in `HomeController.cs` that for today's state its looking like this:

```
//i return Index.cshtml like that:
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel { Tasks = new List<SelectListItem>() };
    foreach (Models.Task task in this.db.Tasks)
    {
        model.Tasks.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = task.Id.ToString(), Text = task.Name });
    }

    return this.View(model);
}

//i recive form from Index.cshtml here
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FromInput(IndexViewModel model)
{

    var result = new MethodViewModel() //app logic, look at another view models in Index and Method
    return this.View("Succes", model: result);            
}
```

My question is, how to return `Succes.cshtml` from my `FromInput` method to `Index.cshtml` as partial view? I want to see output from `FromInput` method not as another `Succes.cshtml` but as part of `Index.cshtml` (thats why i mentioned `Partial Html`, maybe it will work but i dont know how)  What i need to do first? What changes i need to make to make it simple?

**EDIT:**

Im trying some options:

To my `Index.cshtml` i added `div` on below of `html document` and another button :

```
<div id="output">

</div>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

And to `Index.cshtml` i added `script`:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () { myFunction() };
function myFunction() {
    $.get('@Url.Action("FromInput", "Home")', function(data) {
    $('#output').replaceWith(data);
    });
}
```

But it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first call your **Partial view** in **Index.cshtml** and then after when you submit the form you can fill that partial view model and return the partial view.

I've created a demo for you please have look below code and change accordingly.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Example.Models.Test
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<div class="">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "Form1" }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Result, new { @class = "form-control" })

        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>

<div>
    @if (ViewBag.Sucess != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialPage", Model);
    }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Test  mdltest)
{
   //Your data processing over here
   ViewBag.Sucess = "yes"; //For prevent partial view calling when form not submit
   return View("_PartialPage", mdltest);
}
```

**Partial Page**

```
@model Example.Models.Test

@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

<h3>Partial view result</h3>

<h4>@Model.Result</h4>
```

**Note: Let me know if you have any query for the above code.**

Comment: Sorry, but your example not work properly. After clicking "Submit" its true that we r staying on `Index` route, but `cshtml` is reloaded to `_PartialPage`. I want to stay in `Index.cshtml` with all content of it and (for example) add your `_PartialPagr` in the bottom of a page. I dont wont to see only `_partialPage` content, but `Index.cshtml` content and `_PartialPage.cshtml` content in same html

Comment: I've added new partial page code on above answer, hope your partial page will be same as, Index.cshtml never reloaded when you return other partial pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Begin.Form` to `Ajax.BeginForm`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FromInput", "Home", new AjaxOptions {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "yourDivId"
}))
```

Change from

```
return this.View("Succes", model: result);
```

to

```
return PartialView("Success", model);
```

You can reference this link for more detail implementation
[How to use Simple Ajax Beginform in Asp.net MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095443/how-to-use-simple-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Could you tell me how it will work? I click Submit, then how `Succes.cshtml` will display (for example) below form?