# Knockoutjs Validation for areSame or mustMatch examples

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to use the Knockoutjs Validation add on from GitHub. Most of it seems to work just fine but when I try to use the extended validation mustEqual(password/confirm password) it does not seem to do anything.  What am I missing?

I would very much like to learn this extender technique for future use.

(also this whole html and javascript get loaded to the page via AJAX call. if that has anything to do with it.)

My javascript

```
    function UserAccount(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Password = ko.observable(data.Password).extend({ required: true, minlength: 6, message: "Password is required", maxLength: 12 });

        self.Firstname = ko.observable(data.Firstname).extend({ required: true, minlength: 6, message: "Firstname is required", maxLength: 40 });
        self.Lastname = ko.observable(data.Lastname).extend({ required: true, minlength: 6, message: "Lastname is required", maxLength: 40 });
        self.Email = ko.observable(data.Email).extend({ required: true, minlength: 6, message: "Email is required", email: true, maxLength: 90 });
        self.ConfirmPassword = ko.observable().extend({ mustEqual: self.Password()});
        ...........................Other Code............
        }

    ko.validation.rules['mustEqual'] = {
        validator: function (val, otherVal) {
            alert("Hello");
            return val === otherVal;
        },
        message: 'The field must equal {0}'
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {


        ko.applyBindings(new UserAccount(initdata), $("#UserAccount").get(0));
        ko.validation.registerExtenders();

    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your custom validator code is OK. But you are not calling correctly the `ko.validation.registerExtenders();` method.

Although it is not explicitly stated but you need to call `ko.validation.registerExtenders();` **before** you are calling `ko.applyBindings`.

So to fix your code you just need to write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.validation.registerExtenders();
    ko.applyBindings(new UserAccount(initdata), $("#UserAccount").get(0));
});
```

But you will face another problem: the `mustEqual` validator is for comparing to static values so it won't work if you want to compare two properties like password with confirm password.

What you need is something like the [user contributed "Are Same" validator](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules#are-same):

```
ko.validation.rules['areSame'] = {
    getValue: function (o) {
        return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
    },
    validator: function (val, otherField) {
        return val === this.getValue(otherField);
    },
    message: 'The fields must have the same value'
};
```

What you can use like:

```
self.Password = ko.observable(data.Password).extend({
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    message: "Password is required",
    maxLength: 12
});
self.ConfirmPassword = ko.observable().extend({
    areSame: self.Password
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/trvz7/1).

Comment: That worked.  I was actually working with the areSame function at first but could not get it to work.  I switched to the mustEqual because it looked simpler. Should the ko.validation... and ko.applyBindings always be in a $(document).ready?

Comment: The `ko.applyBindings` should be called after your DOM is loaded so the `$(document).ready` is a good place to put it. The `ko.validation.registerExtenders();` should be called AFTER you have defined ALL your custom validators. So it can be called directly after `ko.validation.rules['areSame'] = { }` so it is not necessary to call it in the `$(document).ready`.

Comment: How do I stop the validation from firing when the page first loads?