# Stop Knockoutjs validation during applyBindings (init/onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

How do I stop the validation from firing when the page first loads? I want the validation to fire when the textbox gets edited or has focus and loses focus but not when the page first loads.

My Loading code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

         ko.validation.configure({
             registerExtenders: true,
             messagesOnModified: false,
             decorateElement: true,
             errorClass: 'error',
             insertMessages: true,
             parseInputAttributes: true,
             messageTemplate: 'customMessageTemplate'
         });


        ko.applyBindings(new UserAccount(initdata), $("#UserAccount").get(0));

    });

   function UserAccount(data) {
        var self = this;


        self.UserName = ko.observable(data.UserName).extend({ required: { message: "Username is required" }, minlength: 6, maxLength: 12 });
        self.Password = ko.observable(data.Password).extend({ required:  { message: "Password is required" }, minlength: 6, maxLength: 12 });
        self.Firstname = ko.observable(data.Firstname).extend({ required: { message: "Firstname is required" }, minlength: 6, maxLength: 40 });
        ...... other code .....
     }
```

I have been trying to research this but nothing comes up that seems to work.  I think there might be something in ko.validation.configuration 'messagesOnModified: false' (I tried true, and deleting that all together).

Comment: Can you post your `customMessageTemplate`? Because without the `messageTemplate` the `messagesOnModified: true,` should exactly do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track: you need to set `messagesOnModified: true` otherwise the validation messages will be shown on load also.

However it is not working for you because you need to use the [`validationMessage` binding](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings#validationmessage) in your `messageTemplate` otherwise it won't honor the `messagesOnModified` setting.

So you will need to change your template something like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="customMessageTemplate">
    <span data-bind="validationMessage: field"></span>
</script>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/NvK39/).

Comment: I played with the jsfiddle but now the required validator message does not show up.  I even simplified it to just required: true  It will only change if I type a blank space into the field and then put the focus somewhere else.  I thought it would fire the required when it loses focus? (I am not next to the code I was working on last night).  my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NvK39/13/

Comment: If you check your browser console after clicking on hit me you will see: `Uncaught ReferenceError: isValid is not defined ` because to have the isValid proeprty you need to call `self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);` in your viewmodel. Then you use the `isValid()` property and use the `self.errors.showAllMessages();` to show the validation messages. See in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/bDntj/

Comment: think of this property as `messagesOnlyOnModified`. it's badly named