# Get DropDownListFor selected value into Ajax.ActionLink call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I get the `DropDownListFor` selected value into the `ActionLink` route value (`OrderId`)?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Orders, "OrderId", "Total"))

@Ajax.ActionLink("View Order", "OrderDetails", 
    new 
    { 
        OrderId = 1 // Dropdown value here!
    },
    new AjaxOptions() 
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "OrderDetailsDiv",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    })

<div id="OrderDetailsDiv"></div>
```

I am using MVC 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put your dropdown list and link in an AjaxForm?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("OrderDetails", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "OrderDetailsDiv" }))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Orders, "OrderId", "Total"))
    <input type="submit" value="View Order" />
}
```

You would have a controller method named OrderDetails, which takes a model object, containing a property with name CustomerId.

See this answer for more information on AjaxForms and models: [Using Ajax.BeginForm with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor)

For more information: http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx

Otherwise, I would do a post using JavaScript/jQuery, where you can retrieve the dropdown value, before making the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Even with the AjaxForm, how do I get the `DropDownListFor` selected value?

Comment: Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor