# How to turn Html.BeginForm into Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

The following works, but how do I convert this to an Ajax Call?

```
<section id="loginWindow">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>

}
</section>
```

Comment: Have you checked out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410121/1831275)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your form to this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Make sure your Login action returns the redirect URL, in case of a successful login, and add this script to your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(result) {
        if(result.url) {
            window.location.href = result.url;
        }
    }
</script>
```