# Post selected dropdown to controller MVC using AJAX or other way

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to post the selected item's id from dropdown to post method of same controller and the render the content in same view
PLease help me fast :(

My View

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.hotelmodel.SelectedHotelId, Model.hotelmodel.DrpHotelList)
<div>
<p>@Model.percentageoccupied</p>
 <p>@Model.Revenue</p>
 <p>@Model.UnSold</p>
<div>
```

MY HttpGetMethod

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Counter()
    {
        var personid = ((PersonModel)Session["PersonSession"]).PersonId;
        var model = new CounterforModel();

        model.hotelmodel.DrpHotelList = iCommonservice.GetHotelListByPersonId(personid);

        return View(model);
    }
```

My HttpPostMethod

```
     [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Counter(int id)
        {
            var result = iCommonservice.LoadCounter(id);
            model.percentageoccupied = Convert.ToInt32(result[0].percentageoccupied);
            model.Revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(result[0].Revenue);
            model.UnSold = Convert.ToInt32(result[0].UnSold);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: i pass this SelectedHotelId to a service class which will fetch me list of percentage occupied, revenue and unsold values as you can see on the httpost method.

Comment: the problem is the DropDownList don't post back the selected values.

Comment: i havent implemented ajax call. i am new to ajax.  i want to know the ajax syntax for my requirement. yes, the CounterforModel contain complex property named hotelmodel which contains a property int SelectedHotelid

Comment: the parameter is just a prototype.  i have updated my actionresult

Answer (score 0):

In your POST method pass your View Model as parameter. Then you can use the posted `hotelModel.SelectedHotelId` for what you need, update the model values and pass your updated model to the View.

```
    public ActionResult Counter(CounterforModel model)
    {
        var result = iCommonservice.LoadCounter(model.hotelmodel.SelectedHotelId);
        model.percentageoccupied = Convert.ToInt32(result[0].percentageoccupied);
        model.Revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(result[0].Revenue);
        model.UnSold = Convert.ToInt32(result[0].UnSold);

        return View(model);
    }
```

If you want, you can use `@Ajax.BeginForm()` or `jQuery .ajax()` to make an ajax call to your action. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor).