# How to create Splash Screen in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a splash screen when i click a save button showing message "Your data are being save. Please wait...". Im using MVC 5 for my development.

Below i created a div:

```
<div id="divSplash" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; display:none">
<p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
    Your data are being save. Please wait...<img src="../../Images/ajax-loading.gif">
</p>
</div>
```

Really appreciate if your guys can help to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you posting the data using ajax?

Comment: No..i using post method in MVC to save the data..

Comment: As soon as you click a 'submit' button, you leave the page, so attempting to display a message on a page which no longer exists would be kind of pointless.

Comment: i need to create the loading image because when the user click the save button, i will take 2-3 minutes to save the data into the db..any suggestion on how to create it?

Comment: One option would be to post the form using ajax, then you can display the loading image immediately before the call, then in the success callback, redirect to another view.

Comment: do you have example @stephen on how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an ajax call and use something like this:

```
$.getJson()("/ap/...,
 function(data){
//logic here
$("#divSplash").show();
//do processing
$("#divSplash").hide();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Ajax Form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PerformAction",
    new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId="divSplash", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<div id="divSplash" style="display: none;">
    <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

**How to use [Ajax.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor?rq=1)**
*That is the old post but having very clear explanation.*

Comment: hi @aswini..here im using this code: using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formID" })).. how can i change it using the ajax.beginform ?

Comment: @eikaz - Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem. Thanks