# Partial view won't render after ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass list of Objects. I am passing the data threw ajax call, ajax returns the results as expected, so the ajax call gets the correct results but partial view won't render.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetXlFile()
{
    List<ListMatchDetails> lstPreview = new List<ListMatchDetails>();

    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
    {
        var xlFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["FileToPreview"];
        HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(xlFile);
        if (null != filebase && filebase.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            if (String.Compare(filebase.ContentType, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
            {
                using (Stream stream = filebase.InputStream)
                {
                    IExcelDataReader reader = null;

                    if (filebase.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                    }
                    else if (filebase.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                    }

                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    DataSet dsResult = reader.AsDataSet();
                    DataTable dtResult = dsResult.Tables[0];
                    if (dtResult.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
                        {
                            ListMatchDetails lmd = new ListMatchDetails();
                            lmd.FirstName = (dr[0] != DBNull.Value) ? dr[0].ToString() : string.Empty;
                            lmd.LastName = (dr[1] != DBNull.Value) ? dr[0].ToString() : string.Empty;

                            lstPreview.Add(lmd);
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return PartialView("_ExcelGrid", lstPreview);
}
```

view

```
@using app.Models;
@model IEnumerable<ListMatchDetails>

@{
    if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        ListMatchDetails row = Model.FirstOrDefault();
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive scrollable table-striped ">
            <thead id="tableHeader">
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => row.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => row.LastName)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="pre-scrollable">

                @foreach (var record in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            @Html.ValueForModel(record.FirstName) 

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValueForModel(record.LastName)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}
```

jquery:

```
$('#btnPreview').click(function () {
                var formData = new FormData();
                var files = $("#btnbrowse").get(0).files;
                if (files.length > 0) { formData.append("FileToPreview", files[0]); }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ListMatch/GetXlFile',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        //$('#record').html(result)
                        $('._ExcelGrid').json(result);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //alert('Click Called');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: I added code to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat comparing your action method to your jQuery ajax call, it looks like you're trying to parse the result of the ajax call as a JSON string but you're returning the `_ExcelGrid` partial view.  Unless the `_ExcelGrid` partial view is returning valid JSON, that's going to break when it attempts to parse it as JSON.

I can't tell how it's supposed to be because I'm not sure what `._ExcelGrid` is in your view, but generally speaking you can either change the action method to return JSON instead of a partial view and then parse/handle the JSON on the client side or assign the returned partial view to the element with `$("._ExcelGrid").html(result)`.  Which way you handle it is up to you.

If you opt to return the partial view, for completionist sake I'd change the `dataType` in your ajax call to `html`, because you're not expecting JSON anymore.  You probably also want to set the `contentType` to the type of content that you're sending to the server, you can occasionally run into funny errors if you're not explict.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to use $('#record').html(result). Make sure you have something like

```
<div id="record">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you past your roadblock.  Please let me know if you want me to add more code pertaining to your question.

_ExcelGrid.cshtml

```
A Partial View
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult GetXlFile()
    {
        return PartialView("_ExcelGrid");
    }

    public ActionResult GetXlFile(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
@*credit to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor*@
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index800</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('form').submit(function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <input type="submit" value="OK" />
            }
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Greet for the day !!

Have you defined the partial view on your main page? if not you need to define partial view on your main page just like

```
<div id="dvExcelGrid">
    @Html.Partial("_ExcelGrid", "your model")
   </div>
```