# use ajax.beginform in the view but controller does not recognize as ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It is na asp.net mvc 5 app developped useing vb.net
I use Ajax.beginform in the view but the controller when it retuns the request, does not recognize as an ajax request. 
Here is the code for the view

```
<div Class="modal-dialog">
    <div Class="modal-content">
        <div Class="modal-header">
            <Button type="button" Class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></Button>
            <h4 Class="modal-title">Edit Nome</h4>
        </div>
        @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Nomes", Nothing,
                                                New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST", .OnSuccess = "UpdateSuccess"},
                                                New With {.Class = "form-horizontal", .role = "form"}))

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @<div Class="modal-body">
...........
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-20">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        End using
    </div>
</div>
```

And her is the code for the controller

```
<HttpPost>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Public Async Function Edit(modelNome As NomeVM) As Task(Of ActionResult)

            If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
                Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                Return View(If(Request.IsAjaxRequest(), "Edit", "Edit"), modelNome)
            End If

            Dim nome As Nome = MaptoModel(modelNome)

            dbContext.Nome.Attach(nome)
            dbContext.Entry(nome).State = EntityState.Modified
            Dim task = dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
            Await task

            If task.Exception IsNot Nothing Then
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to update the Nome")
                Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                Return View(If(Request.IsAjaxRequest(), "Edit", "Edit"), modelNome)
            End If

            If Request.IsAjaxRequest() Then
                Return Content("success")
            End If

            Return RedirectToAction("Index")

        End Function
```

Comment: check your browser network tab and see what type of request it is when you submit the form (xhr or not)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js . You can not use a cdn, instead go to manage nuget.  Install jquery.unobtrusive-ajax and reference it.

Credit to [Using Ajax.BeginForm with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor)

Here is an example

View:

```
@ModelType VisualBasic.MyViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexValid100</title>
    @*MAKE SURe these references are included*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    @*get nuget for jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min, cdn is for mvc3 and won't work*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "result"}))
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Foo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Foo)
        @<input type="submit" value="OK" />
    End Using
</body>
</html>
```

Controller/Model:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class MyViewModel
    Public Property Foo() As String
End Class

Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <HttpPost>
    Function Index(ByVal myViewModel As MyViewModel) As ActionResult
        Return Content("Thanks", "text/html")
    End Function

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View(New MyViewModel())
    End Function
```